# Material 2 md-tab-nav-bar wraps on mobile

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I want to use tabs for navigation. I followed [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/component/tabs) verbatim:

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
  <a md-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{tabLink.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This looks and works great on desktop:

[image: Looks great on desktop]

but looks hideous on mobile:

[image]

---

If I use the md-tab-group (non-nav) tabs, they look great on mobile:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Navigation tab 1"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Navigation tab 2"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Navigation tab 3"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Navigation tab 4"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Navigation tab 5"></md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, or is this this a bug in Material 2? Is there a way to make `md-tab-nav-bar` responsive, or to make `md-tab-group` work as a nav bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I just found this issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2177) that outlines a disconnect between md-tabs and md-tab-nav-bar:

> The current "md-tab-group" implementation is already looking great (Dynamic height, scrolling, pagination when tabs exceed container width etc..) But with the "md-tab-nav-bar" component none of these features are available.

It's been assigned and has an "important" tag, so I guess this is an acknowledged by the Material team.

Be sure to head over there and give it a  to help get it prioritized.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>` doesn't work as the `<mat-tab-group>`. A possible quick solution I used is to just make the container scroll:

```
.mat-tab-nav-bar {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Which looks acceptable and is clean enough, but shows the native scrollbar while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential workaround found at the bottom of the issue that adamport mentioned.

Paraphrased from the workaround (original credits to daiky00):

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab *ngFor="let yourVariable of yourLinks">
             <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                <a  mat-tab-link 
                      [routerLink]="yourVariable.path"
                      [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
                      routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive">
                {{yourVariable.data['label']}} <!-- or however your links are set up-->
                </a>
            </ng-template>
       </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</nav>
```

Comment: set tab successfully on reload but it shows first tab selected color.

Comment: I noticed that issue as well but didn't have time to fix it. Let me know if you find anything

Answer (score 0):

I did a very nice workaround. You can use the MatTab's event 'selectedTabChange' to make it looks like a Link:

--HTML--

```
  <mat-tab-group 
  (selectedTabChange)="onLinkClick($event)" 
  [selectedIndex]="selectedTab" 
   mat-stretch-tabs>
   <mat-tab *ngFor="let link of links" label="TabLabel">


   </mat-tab>

  </mat-tab-group>
```

--MODEL--

```
export class NavOption{
 routerLink:string;
 title:string;
 constructor(routerLink:string,title:string){
    this.routerLink = routerLink;
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

--TS--

```
import { MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { NavOption } from '../model/route.model';

links = Array<NavOption >=[...]

constructor(private router: Router) {}


onLinkClick(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
  console.log(event);
  let tabTitle = event.tab.textLabel;
  let routerLink = this.navs.find(n => n.title == tabTitle ).routerLink;

   this.router.navigate(['/' + routerLink]);
  }
```

It's working good, only there is no entrance animation.